Is it possible to create custom fields for Interest Tags?
I need to create External ID fields for both Interest Tags and Tag Category. I was able to create the external ID for Tag Category, but I'm unable to do the same for Interest Tags. I managed to get into Interest Tag's object manager page, but it shows an error message whenever I click on the New button.
Is there any workaround for this situation? I'm considering maybe using a Custom Object and then sync to the Standard Object.



As per documentation you cannot add custom fields to "Interest Tags".
The reason being its a virtual object built on top of "Topic" object.
Hence it is also not available from Object Manager.
Documentation : Interest Tags Consideration and Limitations

